# Help on separating terms in autosuggestion

Tags: forms, accessibility, keyboard-shortcuts

I was working on a solution where we introduce an autosuggestion component to our users so we can enable them to fill the required information in a better way. This list use more than 1000 words in our DB so while the user is typing we can suggest terms to fill. Easy:

[image: suggestion 1]

Sometimes, the user has to introduce two terms, so my idea was to simply enable this by separating with a ",". Easy:

[image: suggestion 2]

**The problem:**
I've realized by looking at the DB that some terms actually has a "," in their names, for example:

> Word 7, something

So this pretty much destroy my idea of using "," to separate different terms, because if the user is typing the correct name that has a coma in it, the suggestion fill will simply start providing suggestions to a new term.
I cannot force the user to use this list because its items are going to be growing in time, this is not a stone source of truth.
I though in using [Chips from Material Design](https://material.io/components/chips) but some users simply copy and paste a whole list of terms (and keep in mind that I cannot automatically convert this to chips because some names actually have a , in it). I thought in provide a "Tab" key to separate terms but this will imply an accessibility issue. I also though in use one input for each product but this will mean a potential constraint for users.
I'm really stuck in here and I've reading a lot of documentation about autosuggestions to see if I can get another option but can find any.

I feel that I hit a wall here.

Does anybody has an alternative idea in mind to provide an easy way to contemplate "," in an autosuggestion component while we need the user to add more terms in it?

Comment: ^ See those 3 tags you added to this question... do it like that.

Comment: Thought in that, but that uses "," to separate tags betweem them, and keep in mind that if a user insert a term with coma in the middle it's going to be disrupted by this auto separation logic

Answer (score 0):

Try to use one of multiselect controls which are available on different platforms.

I mean like this one (just the first from Google search) which you can test immediately: [Multi-select boxes (pillbox)](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage#multi-select-boxes-pillbox):

[image]

Also you can see one of examples right here at User Experince Questions home page:

[image: Multiple selection example]